# How to sum different fields in XSL when some might be null?

Tags: xslt, null, sum, xsl-fo

I have the following XSL :

```
    <xsl:value-of select='translate(format-number(
        Gaz/Baf/CH4
        + Gaz/Std/CH4
        + Gaz/Bsa/CH4
        + Gaz/Bbs/CH4
        + Gaz/Bhf/CH4
        + Gaz/Bin/CH4
        , "### ### ### ##0.######"),".",",")' />
```

The sum adds up nicely when all my items have values. However, if one of them is null (`<CH4 xsi:nil="true"/>`), then my sums become `NaN`.

So far I tried adding a new function. But it's not supported by the pdf generator we use. (*System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: 'xsl:function' is still not implemented*)

I tried adding a C# function to add as an *XsltArgumentList*. A simple `return value ?? 0;` But I also get an exception : _System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Params or values of an extention function with a Clr 'Nullable`1' type are not managed _

And now I'm trying to use a `xsl:variable`, but I find no example where they add value to the variable (Is a variable static once defined?)

So, any suggestions?

Comment: Which XSLT engine does the PDF genarator use? Does it support XSL 1 or 2?

Comment: We're using [telerik's engine](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/n_telerik_apoc_render.html). This use is not supported by telerik but... yeah, I'm limited to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tell my students to use a predicate to filter out those members that are not numbers.

So, in XSLT 1 I would use the following, relying on the principle that `NaN!=NaN`:

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(format-number(
    sum( ( Gaz/Baf/CH4
         | Gaz/Std/CH4
         | Gaz/Bsa/CH4
         | Gaz/Bbs/CH4
         | Gaz/Bhf/CH4
         | Gaz/Bin/CH4 )[number(.)=number(.)] )
    , "### ### ### ##0.######"),".",",")' />
```

In XSLT 2 it would be more elegant as:

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(format-number(
    sum( (Gaz/Baf/CH4
         | Gaz/Std/CH4
         | Gaz/Bsa/CH4
         | Gaz/Bbs/CH4
         | Gaz/Bhf/CH4
         | Gaz/Bin/CH4 )[. castable as xs:double] )
    , "### ### ### ##0.######"),".",",")' />
```

(Repaired per observations from LarsH; thank you Lars.)

Comment: This is helpful, but ... don't you want the predicate to go inside the `sum(...)` parentheses?

Comment: Of course!  I'm missing a couple of parentheses, actually ... I'll edit it right now.  Thank you, Lars.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sum` of a node set. Like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(format-number(
  sum(Gaz/Baf/CH4|Gaz/Std/CH4|Gaz/Bsa/CH4|Gaz/Bbs/CH4|Gaz/Bhf/CH4|Gaz/Bin/CH4),
  '### ### ### ##0.######'), '.', ',')" />
```

---

**Update**

You could perhaps try

```
<xsl:variable name="ch4" select="Gaz/Baf/CH4|Gaz/Std/CH4|Gaz/Bsa/CH4|Gaz/Bbs/CH4|Gaz/Bhf/CH4|Gaz/Bin/CH4"/>
```

Then the variable `$ch4` will contain a set of nodes that match that expression. You can see how many nodes are in it using

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($ch4)"/>
```

and you should be able to calculate the sum using

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($ch4)"/>
```

Comment: I had to remove the parenthesis to have it work : `sum(Gaz/Baf|Std|Bsa|Bbs|Bhf|Bin/CH4)`. But I still got `NaN`. :( (even `sum(Gaz/Baf/CH4)` return NaN!)

Comment: OK I was trying to be too clever. I've amended my answer: try that.

Comment: Still NaN. I think my generator is just bad. It doesn't even know the [sum function with 2 args](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-sum)...

Comment: You're looking at XPath 2.0. [This is the XPath 1.0 sum()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum). It's pretty basic. Is it the Telerik engine that's doing the transform? I know nothing about it but it seems to be a problem. Does `sum(Gaz/*/CH4)` work perhaps? Is it even what you want? The only way I can see seems to be to write an extension.

Comment: @Kraz: Are you saying that `Gaz/Baf/CH4` exists, but `sum(Gaz/Baf/CH4)` is `NaN`? That's very broken.

Comment: Yes, CH4 is in the XML, but marked as null (`<CH4 xsi:nil="true"/>`). About your update : The count work, but sum still return NaN.

Comment: @Kraz: I guess you're happy with the solution that you found? You should mark it as accepted so that people know it doesn't need any more work. Let me know if you want any more help, and please show a sample of the XML if you do.

Comment: My solution was fine, but I find G. Ken Holman' solution to be better. For a sample of XML, I'm not sure I'm allowed to post it unchanged and I simplified it a lot (the whole thing is > 700 LOC and I do 3 sums of ~15 elements)

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution using C#

My first attempt was :

```
    public decimal AddNaN(decimal? val)
    {
        return val ?? 0;
    }
```

but it didn't like the `decimal?`

So I tried something else :

```
    public decimal AddNaN(string val)
    {
        decimal num = 0;
        decimal.TryParse(val, out num);
        return num;
    }
```

Which worked.